# What is the best statistical test to use when you have three independent variables and one dependent with two levels?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, model

I have a research project where I collected data in which has three independent variables(Extra, Agree, and Neur) and one dependent variable with two levels (High Avoid and Low Avoid). Below is a portion of my data(the data does not have the same number of rows):

*High Avoid*

```
Extra  Agree     Neur          
08      39       -4     
29      37       21     
16      36       3 
22      34       10     
19      31       09     
09      24       24  
17      35       14     
41      39       24     
25      36       20
```

*Low Avoid*

```
Extra  Agree     Neur          
24      31       31     
41      33       06     
21      32       13 
30      41       29     
18      30       07     
26      42       17  
09      -10      02     
32      45       28     
42      49       20  
35      42       08     
11      42       08     
29      30       08
```

Comment: What do you want to test? Given your tags, something makes you think that this is ANOVA. I see a similarity, but what is the similarity that you see?

Comment: I want to see if there is a difference between the two levels of the dependent variable in terms of the independent variables within each section(high avoid and low avoid)! @Dave

Comment: I thought it would be a three way anova since i have three independent and one dependent, but i realized my dependent variable is not continuous so I am starting to think that statistical method will not work @Dave

Comment: In other words, do ANOVA but with this binary data  instead of continuous (normal) data...?

Comment: could you clarify your question! @Dave

Comment: Do a 3-sample comparison but with binary data, determining if the probabilities (instead of means) of each group are the same

Comment: Do you know which program is best to do that on? I have R and excel currently @Dave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106729/discussion-between-dave-and-sherien-hassan).

Comment: I think "The best" is one of the most dangerous words in statistics.